# エラーの意味が分かりません。どういう意味なのでしょうか？

Tags: python, opencv

pythonで、OpenCVを使って画像を合成（重ね合わせ）したいと思っています。

**実行環境:**
Python 3.8.8
OpenCV 4.5.3

以下にソースの抜粋を転記します。

```
def PictureAdd_a_lot_of_face():
    StrtPos_x = 10
    StrtPos_y = 10

    img1 = cv2.imread(Path1)
    img1 = cv2.cvtColor(img1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

    img2 = cv2.imread(Path2)
    img2 = cv2.cvtColor(img2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

    x = 10
    y = 25

    print('img2----->', img2.shape)
    print('img1----->', img1.shape)
    img2[StrtPos_y: y + StrtPos_y, StrtPos_x: x + StrtPos_x] = img1
```

上記のソースを実行すると、末尾の `img2[省略] = img1` のところで、下記のようなエラーが出ています。エラーメッセージの後に、print文の出力がありました。

このエラーはどういう意味なのでしょうか？また、`shape (25,10,3)` というのが何を意味するのかも不明です。

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (150,150,3) into shape (25,10,3)
img2-----> (500, 700, 3)
img1-----> (150, 150, 3)
```

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: エラーについてはこんな記事が参考になるかも。[とほほ、、、numpyの初歩を理解していなかったでござる](https://qiita.com/tagtagtag/items/7f85a776bbff261064f8), [【エラー解決】ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (*,*,*) into shape (*,*,*)](https://pycarnival.com/valueerror_broadcast_opencv/) そして実際にやりたいことはこちらの方が近いのでは？ [OpenCV 入門 (7) - 画像上に別の画像を描画](https://note.com/npaka/n/nddb33be1b782)

Comment: 重ね合わせる領域の width と height が合っていない、という事なので `x, y = img1.shape[:2]` とします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (150,150,3) into shape (25,10,3)

配列のサイズが不一致という意味です。（正確にはブロードキャスト出来ないというエラーです）
`img2[StrtPos_y: y + StrtPos_y, StrtPos_x: x + StrtPos_x]`のサイズが(25,10,3)で、`img1`のサイズが(150,150,3)です。

`img2[StrtPos_x:StrtPos_x + img1.shape[0], StrtPos_y:StrtPos_y + img1.shape[1]] = img1`でimg2の左上部分にimg1を合成出来るかと思います。

Comment: merinoさん、ありがとうございました。
教わった方法でできました。

＞img2[StrtPos_y:StrtPos_y + img1.shape[1], StrtPos_x:StrtPos_x + img1.shape[0]] = img1